# Executorservice wait after tasks are finished

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice, runnable

I have this code and what it does is wait for all tasks are complished and only then return values to the widget. WorkerThread is a runnable that needs to finish before next loop.

```java
final ScheduledExecutorService ecs = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(size2/2);
while(size2>1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size2/2; i++) {
        Runnable worker = null;
        try {
            worker = new WorkerThread(players.take(), players.take() ,area,players);
        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
            interruptedException.printStackTrace();
        }
        ecs.submit(worker);
    }
    area.append("\n\n next Round");
    size2=size2/2;
}
```

So what I need to do is to have in this case 8 tasks complete, get values that they append to the widget, then wait for example 2 seconds and proceed with the loop now with 4 tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Phaser`.

```
Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1); // Create Phaser instance
final ScheduledExecutorService ecs = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(size2/2);
while(size2>1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size2/2; i++) {
        Runnable worker = null;
        try {
            worker = new WorkerThread(players.take(), players.take() ,area,players);
        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
            interruptedException.printStackTrace();
        }
        phaser.register(); // Register a party
        ecs.submit(worker);
    }
    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // Wait for completion of all tasks
    area.append("\n\n next Round");
    size2=size2/2;
}
```

Here is your consumer.

```
public class WorkerThread {

    public WorkerThread(Phaser phaser) {
        this.phaser = phaser;
    }

    public void run() {
        processThings();
        phaser.arriveAndDeregister(); // Deregister a party
    }

}
```